# How to make a .SQL file password protected?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, passwords, password-protection

Currently I am working on a .NET application in which I am calling 3 stored procedures. But while delivering it to end user, we should not give access to him to see the logic in my stored procedures.
So I wanted to keep password to my .SQL files and planning to give my password in c# code open when it is required to execute. Since we are not going to send c# code to the end client, he cannot see the password also.

But now I do not know how to keep .SQL file password protected.

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by .sql file?  Where is database installed?  And just because you don't send the c# source code does not mean they cannot see the password.

Comment: You can have the SQL files as embedded resources in your EXE. This is the same level of security as having the password in code, just a lot easier. Should work with people who never heard of Reflector. When you create SP in database use `WITH ENCRYPTION` but again an admin can retrieve the original text. It all depends on how secure you want it to be and how much effort you are willing to invest.

Answer (score 0):

You should setup a secure FTP OR SVN in my opinion.  If you must simply send files I recommend using a Password Protected RAR or ZIP File.  You cannot password protect a .sql file from what I know.